# HTML text really out of place

Tags: html

So I recently decided to download a HTML template for my site, after downloading it and setting it up it was going well, but text goes to the bottom rather than where I want it to go, here's some screenshots

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBz9M.jpg - That big empty box is where I want the text to go

https://i.stack.imgur.com/auo8m.jpg - That is where the text actually goes

I'm new to HTML so excuse my noobness, but I did really well before running into this.

Here's the text code

```
<center><h2>Updates</h2></center>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em"> 20 September 2014 - You can now earn gold by working.</p>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em">20 September 2014 - Username now displays in the navigation pane.</p>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em">20 September 2014 - Your Stats page now fully functional.</p>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em">19 September 2014 - Added new registration page with increased security and validation.</p>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em">19 September 2014 - Removed login box from every page after logging in.</p>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em">19 September 2014 - Gold now a resource.</p>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em">19 September 2014 - Incorrect login now displays an error message</p>

<p style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em" >19 September 2014 - Added Rankings, Your Stats   and Earn Gold pages. Not functional at the moment but will be as soon as possible.</p>

<p><a href=\"main.php\">Back to main page</a></p>
```

That is all on a seperate page, I have the rest (background and stuff) saved as header.php, let me know if you need that

Entire template code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>Free Layout(from Dandon.net)</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
<center>
<table heigh="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" background="images/lbar.png" height="500" width="38"></td>
<td valign="top">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="631">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><img src="images/banner.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="450">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td background="images/nav.png" height="17" width="178">
<div style="color:white" align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-1">Main</font></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.php">» Home</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="stats.php">» Your stats</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="units.php">» Units</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="rankings.php">» Rankings</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="userson.php">» Online players</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="updates.php">» Updates</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php">» Logout</a><br>
</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td background="images/nav.png" height="17" width="178">
<div style="color:white" align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"     size="-1">Social</font></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="chat.php">»     Chatroom</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="url">» Forum</a><br>


</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td background="images/divider.png" width="11"></td>
<td valign="top">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="460" width="535">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td background="images/content.png" height="17" width="535">
<div align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-1"></font></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><font color="#ff9900" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"     size="-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom"><img src="images/footer.png"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td colspan="2" background="images/rbar.png" height="500" width="38"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
<div style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em; text-align: center; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;">
Design provided by <a href="http://www.freewebtemplates.com/">Free
Web Templates</a> - your source for free website templates<br>
Supported by <a href="http://www.hosting24.com/" target="_blank">Hosting24.com</a>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: If all that inline css and `<center>` magic is coming from the template I would have asked a refund instead ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa I wrote the code I showed myself, as I said I'm noob :(

Comment: I think it is because that box is part of the header so I can't edit it? If so how do I go about being able to put stuff in there on seperate pages?

Comment: you really should get rid of this template. the only thing you will get out of this is to learn html the wrong way. there are plenty of good beginner tutorials to learn html pretty fast for something you want to do. just ask google about "responsive" or "adaptive website development tutorials for beginners" or something like that :)

Comment: Yeah I learned quite a bit through W3 school, in fact it was the first code I started learning :) It's just I can't create graphics myself, nor do I want to bother someone as I have 0 budget, so a free template sounded good to me

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the inline styling, add some classes and use `text-align:center` to center out your Updates feed. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hyfwgx5g/4/

**EDIT**: So here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hyfwgx5g/6/ .

I wasn't sure if your updates feed is in a separate file or if you're manually adding it into the page. I've added a class `updates-container` to the table cell in which your code should live. Simply add it there, or like I said if you're importing a file add it using the include tag (for example `<?php include 'updates.php';?>` ).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it doesn't solve my problem :3 I think it's cause that part I'm trying to add text to is part of the "header.php"

Comment: @RyanMcKenna Can you post the rest of your template? I've jumped into conclusions that you wanted it centered out at the bottom.

Comment: Posted it all, nah I want it in that box. I made the website in just php but it didn't look good as it was all just random coloured boxes lol edit - also, the part I added is on every page as it is the template for every page, but the text at the bottom is part of a seperate page that uses the template if that makes sense?

Comment: I remember the horrors of learning HTML and working with templates like this one :D Give me a minute

Comment: Horrors all add to the sense of achievement :) and okayy, it's probably something simple I missed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61601/discussion-between-serakiel-and-ryan-mckenna).